# ASP.NET MVC4 get works fine post returns 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC.  I'm working with MVC4 in VS2012.  I have get by id and get all working fine.  When I change my http request in my ajax code from get to post it fails with a 500 error.

So the questions 
1 - how do i debug this kind of issue
2 - why is it happening in this specific instance

I am pretty sure this has something to do with me not understanding what I'm suppose to include in the routing code

The code I think is significant

```
//the controller method
            [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public void PostPatientAppointment(PatientAppointment patientAppointment)
        {
            init();
            updatePatientAppointmentList();

            foreach (PatientAppointment existingPatientAppointment in patientAppointments)
            {
                if (patientAppointmentConflict(existingPatientAppointment, patientAppointment ))
                {
                    throw new HttpException(409, "Conflict");   
                }
            }

            //return patientAppointment;
        }

function onMouseUp(evt) {
    rect = null;
    mouseDown = false;

    //check for conflicting appointments
    //do the xhr request
    //cycle through appointments looking for conflicts
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //open Dojo modal dialogue
                alert("will open dialogue");
            }
            else if( xmlhttp.status == 409)
            {
                alert("There is a conflict with that patient appointment");
            }
            alert("hmm - status was: " + xmlhttp.status );
        }
    }

    var patientAppointment = "{'identity':-1,'doctorId':-1,'patientId':-1,'patientName':null,'startTime':-1, 'endTime':-1,'location':null,'reason':null,'note':null,'recurrenceId':0,'appointmentTypeId':0,'patientShowedUp':false,'confirmed':false,'fullDayEvent':false}";
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/api/PatientAppointment/", true);
    xmlhttp.send(patientAppointment);
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the networking tab inside your browser debugger. Once the 500 is returned check the response body, it contains the error.

In this specific instance I see you have a void method so it returns nothing. If this is supposed to return an `ActionResult` or a `JsonResult` then you are either exceeding the maximum length of the query string (this doesn't seem to be the case) or you are not allowing `HTTP GET` for your `JsonResult` response.